# The file "C:\xampp\tmp\php8911.tmp" does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.4

I after install

```
composer require intervention/image
```

I want to upload image and after submit a form, I get this error.

> The file "C:\xampp\tmp\php1D5F.tmp" does not exist

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    auth()->loginUsingId(1);
    $imagesUrl = $this->uploadImages($request->file('images'));

    $article = auth()->user()->article()->create(array_merge($request->all(), ['images' => $imagesUrl]));
    $article->categories()->attach(request('category'));


    return redirect(route('articles.index'));
}

protected function uploadImages($file)
{
    $year = Carbon::now()->year;
    $imagePath = "/upload/images/{$year}/";
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $file = $file->move(public_path($imagePath) , $filename);

    $sizes = ["300" , "600" , "900"];
    $url['images'] = $this->resize($file->getRealPath() , $sizes , $imagePath , $filename);
    $url['thumb'] = $url['images'][$sizes[0]];

    return $url;
}

private function resize($path , $sizes , $imagePath , $filename)
{
    $images['original'] = $imagePath . $filename;
    foreach ($sizes as $size) {
        $images[$size] = $imagePath . "{$size}_" . $filename;

        Image::make($path)->resize($size, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save(public_path($images[$size]));
    }

    return $images;
}
```

I tried Change the code:

```
    $imagesUrl = $this->uploadImages($request->file('images'));
    return $imagesUrl;
```

It displaied return $imagesUrl well.

```
images  
300 "/upload/images/2018/300_tvto.jpg"
600 "/upload/images/2018/600_tvto.jpg"
900 "/upload/images/2018/900_tvto.jpg"
original    "/upload/images/2018/tvto.jpg"
thumb   "/upload/images/2018/300_tvto.jpg"
```

I think problem from `array_merge`

**So what's the solution?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert ArticleRequest to Request and bring it to the controller page like below.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request(),[
        'title' => 'required|max:250',
        'type' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,bmp',
        'path.*' => 'required|mimes:avi,mp4,.mov,wmv',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);
```